# Gradle cannnot resolve some dependencies while Maven can

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, mvn-repo

I have a Gradle project that requires `org.eclipse.hudson:hudson-core:3.3.3`. It has been working fine until today, when it just says:

```
Could not resolve org.eclipse.hudson:hudson-remoting:3.0.3
```

I created a Maven project with only `hudson-remoting:3.0.3`, it works fine. The jar is also there on the Maven Central. Gradle is able to resolve `hudson-remoting:3.0.2` though, but `hudson-core:3.3.3` requires `hudson-remoting:3.0.3`. What is going on?

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.hudson:hudson-remoting:3.0.3'
}
```

The projects uses bundled Gradle 6.8, created by IntelliJ.

Comment: Does it happen only in IntelliJ IDEA or in the command line Gradle as well?

Comment: @CrazyCoder: It happens with `gradlew` as well. Turns out the `pom` file on Maven central actually defines the version as `3.0.4-SNAPSHOT`. I still don't understand why the error only comes up now. Everything had been working great for over a year.